# CakeEmail Template InPage Css Doesnt Apply

Tags: email, templates, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Problem : 
In Gmail the email template is not viewed like
http://zurb.com/ink/downloads/templates/basic.html
it looks like a simple plain text mail with html tags, without color formatting
[image]

What I Tried :
Template Code Used : http://zurb.com/ink/downloads/templates/basic.html
Copy Pasted in Views\Layouts\Emails\html\default.ctp for a quick check & sent a test mail.

Their Test's says it should work on all major email emails
Test Result : https://litmus.com/pub/85a1b19

Answer (score 1):

That is a nice layout - just not for emails.
For templates HTML emails all style must be inline - style tags are not allowed across many email clients.

Thus, you need to use something like I do to transform the style css into inline css upon sending:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/InlineCssLib.php

Basically, upon generating the final template, an afterLayout() hook of a helper can trigger this.
See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cake-php/B56hAI4VivM/Y21tFavLggcJ) for details on the implementation.

Comment: I try to use this `EmailProcessingHelper` by loading it at the top of HTML email .ctp file like this `$this->Helpers->load('EmailProcessing');` and it works.
But there is problem while sending with emailFormat set to 'both' - the text version of email is also processed by `InlineCssLib`. Could you please advise how to fix that?

Comment: If you send as both, the text should be extracted from the HTML when sending. At this point you can simply strip out the HTML tags. At least that's what I have done. It is only a fallback after all.

Comment: Here is simple solution I've figured out to solve that: http://pastebin.com/YvUb4EgX

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the parameter ->emailFormat('text')? 
ensure that you use ->emailFormat('html')